# Postgresql AFTER UPDATE trigger OLD has no field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a trigger, like many other triggers that fire after update and checks  a field of the `OLD` set.
For some reason this trigger throw this error:

```
ERROR:  record "old" has no field "status"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT NOT (OLD.status = NEW.status) AND NEW.status = 'Success'"
```

This is the body of the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_online_payment_after_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  v_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- If state changed to Success

  IF NOT (OLD.status = NEW.status) AND NEW.status = 'Success' THEN
    -- Find any invoices attached and set them to paid
    FOR v_rec IN
      SELECT invoice_id_fk
        FROM online_payment_invoice
        WHERE online_payment_id_fk = NEW.online_payment_id
    LOOP
      UPDATE invoice
        SET paid_date = CURRENT_DATE,
            updator_id_fk = -2,
            updated = LOCALTIMESTAMP
        WHERE invoice_id = v_rec.invoice_id_fk;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_online_payment_after_update
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON online_payment
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_online_payment_after_update();
```

Weird thing is that it actually seems to run the invoice update part of the trigger.

I cannot see what I am missing here.  It does not make sense.

This is the full output:

```
   =>UPDATE online_payment SET status = 'Success' WHERE online_payment_id = 18;
    ERROR:  record "old" has no field "status"
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT NOT (OLD.status = NEW.status) AND NEW.status = 'Success'"
    PL/pgSQL function tr_online_payment_after_update() line 7 at IF
    SQL statement "UPDATE load_unit
          SET load_hinderance = load_hinderance(load_unit_id)
          WHERE load_consign_match_id_fk = v_lcm_id"
    PL/pgSQL function tr_invoice_after_update() line 50 at SQL statement
    SQL statement "UPDATE invoice
            SET paid_date = CURRENT_DATE,
                updator_id_fk = -2,
                updated = LOCALTIMESTAMP
            WHERE invoice_id = v_rec.invoice_id_fk"
    PL/pgSQL function tr_online_payment_after_update() line 14 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Adding the table definition would help.

Comment: If `status` can be null, you should use `if OLD.status is not distinct from NEW.status then ...` to properly deal with null values.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the LOOP is unnecessary (and inefficient) and should be replaced with a singlue `UPDATE` statement

Comment: The loop is inefficient now, because the trigger is not complete.  There are some other actions that needs to be added to the loop still.  But you are correct.  It is inefficient as it is now.  :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the following diagnostic line to the function:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Called % % on %',
   TG_WHEN, TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME;
```

Then run the SQL statement that invokes the trigger and see if the output is what you expect.

Comment: Yes!  I copied the source code of the trigger from another trigger and the first time I ran it, it created the trigger on another table.  I suspected something like that, but by the time I ran into the problem, I could not remember what I used as template.  This diagnostic pointed it out immediately.  Thanks!